# How do I change the font size of the drop-down-menu of a combobox in Delphi Firemonkey XE7?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to change the font size of a combobox in Delphi Firemonkey XE7. The application will be used on a Windows tablet.
It already works so far that the selected item shown in the combobox when "not opened" changes the font size but when I click on the combobox and the drop-down-menu opens, the items in the drop-down-menu have still the default font size. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The source code so far:

```
for i := 0 to combobox1.Count - 1 do
begin
  combobox1.ListBox.ListItems[i].TextSettings.Font.Size := 20;
  combobox1.ListBox.ListItems[i].StyledSettings :=  combobox1.ListBox.ListItems[i].StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Size];
end;
```

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVqHW.jpg) to view picture of the described problem.

Thanks in advance!
Lea

Comment: If you use the Scale property on the combobox it will change the text size of both the box item and the drop down items.

Comment: do you have any code? what i read on the internet about the property seems that it just scales the drop-down-menu but not the font size but i have no idea if that's right and how to use this property :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For use styled ListBox items in ComboBox, set `ComboBox.DropDownKind := TDropDownKind.Custom`

Comment: thanks! that worked. but now the space around the drop-down-item-texts is quite small. can i somehow get a bigger margin or something like that?

Comment: Set ComboBox.ItemHeight.
I think, that is better to create custom styles for ComboBox and ListBoxItem for centralized management of properties

Answer (score 1):

```
Procedure StyleComboBoxItems(ComboBox:TComboBox; Family:string; Size:Single);
var
  Item : TListBoxItem;
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComboBox.Count-1 do begin
    Item := ComboBox.ListItems[i];
    Item.Font.Family := Family; //'Arial';
    Item.Font.Size := Size; //20;
    // Item.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    Item.StyledSettings := Item.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Family,TStyledSetting.Size,TStyledSetting.FontColor];
    // Item.Text := '*'+Item.Text;
  end;
end;

//call like StyleComboBoxItems(cbbXYZ,'Segoe UI',10.0);
//remember to call it everytime you change the cbb list by clearing, adding, deleting etc.
```

Code by JAN BLOMQVIST